# functional DOM and closures, defer until document ready

Tags: javascript, dom

#### Background

I am experimenting a bit with functional programming and DOM manipulation. My objective is to toggle certain style of a DOM element between two values. I have all the required pieces in place, and they work in isolation. Here are the first version of the functions used:

```
const toggleBetween = (...args) => {
    let index=0;
    const ln = args.length;
    return () => {
        const val = args[index];
        index = (index +1)% ln;
        return val;
    }
}

export const toggleStyle = (domNode, name: string, value: any) => {
    const toggleValue = toggleBetween(domNode.style[name], value);
    return () => {
        domNode.style[name] = toggleValue();
    }
}
```

Both functions are very simple. The first one will return a function that will return the next value on the list each time it is called, and the second one returns a function that will toggle the given style property between the current value and the provided one. So far so good.

I also have a couple of functions that grab the required DOM elements:

```
const pickDomA = () => {/* Code that picks and caches DomNode A*/}
const pickDomB = () => {/* Code that picks and caches DomNode B*/}
```

Then they can be used like this

```
const toggleThing = toggleStyle(pickDomA(), 'display', '');
```

#### The problem

The problem arises when I want to initialize a module containing these functions: the document is not ready, trying to fetch the DOM nodes will return null and everything will fail.

The problem is just with startup, the execution will be just fine because those functions are triggered by UI elements that will only be available after document is ready.

#### Question

Is there an elegant yet functional way of deferring DOM node picking until the document is ready?

#### Solution I am not happy with

The best I got so far is encapsulating every argument access in a function that checks if the argument is a function, and if so it executes it and returns the value. Then all I have to do is pass the values encapsulated as functions.

Although that works, I find it a bit fragile and also a bit twisted. If it wasn't because the document initialization everything will be just simpler.

It looks like this:

```
 const getValue = (val) => {    
    if (typeof val === 'function') {
        return val();
    }
    return val;
}

const toggleBetween = (...args) => {
    let index=0;
    const ln = args.length;
    return () => { 
        const val = args[index];
        index = (index +1)% ln;
        return getValue(val);
    }
}

export const toggleStyle = (domNode, name: string, value: any) => {
    const originalValue = memoize(()=> getValue(domNode).style[name]);
    const toggleValue = toggleBetween(originalValue , value);
    return () => {
        getValue(domNode).style[name] = toggleValue();
    }
}
```

As you can see, now every function can take a function instead of a value and execute it to get the value, so DOM picking is deferred until first execution. The reason for the `memoize` is because I only want the first extracted value, this means the original DOM node value.

Then all that I have to do is remove the `()` of the DOM picking functions and everything will be just fine:

```
const toggleThing = toggleStyle(pickDomA, 'display', '');
```

But again, I am not happy with this solution. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: Seems to be  over complicating something simple. This question (whatever the actual question is) is probably better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but not you need to clarify what your actual issue is there also

Comment: I updated your question so it is a question ;-)

Comment: Thanks you @trincot, looks much better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naively, you would just defer the execution of code that would need the document to be ready, i.e. `pickDomA()` and `pickDomB()` should not be executed before.

And that is commonly done like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    const toggleThing = toggleStyle(pickDomA(), 'display', '');
    // rest of code that depends on toggleThing ...
});
```

Or, you make sure the script with `pickDomA()` is placed at the end of the `body` tag: then the DOM will be ready.